# How to remove lines which match lines in another document

Tags: centos7, centos6

So I am running Centos 6.9, but could switch to Centos 7 if needed

If I have 2 txt files, one contains

```
Gold
Silver
Copper
Aluminum
Titanium
```

And my second contains

```
Gold
Silver
Titanium
```

How can I run a command to have a file that contains

```
Copper
Aluminum
```

Summarized: How can I remove lines in a file which match those of another file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done with grep

```
laforge@ncc1701d:~ $ cat file1.txt
Gold
Silver
Copper
Aluminum
Titanium
laforge@ncc1701d:~ $ cat file2.txt
Gold
Silver
Titanium
laforge@ncc1701d:~ $ grep -vf file2.txt file1.txt
Copper
Aluminum
laforge@ncc1701d:~ $ grep -f file2.txt file1.txt
Gold
Silver
Titanium
laforge@ncc1701d:~ $
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked just how I needed!